# Remove outline from details tag or expand and collapse

Tags: javascript, html, css

When you expand or collapse the `details` element, there is an outline.

Is there a way to remove this outline on expand/collapse, but not when we switch between elements using the Tab key?

```css
summary {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

/* The sledgehammer. It removes focus for both
 * select-with-Tab-key and expand events
 **/


/* summary:focus { outline: none; } */


/* An attempt of more intelligent approach. However,
 * it doesn't really work.
 **/

details[open] summary,
summary:active {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>

<details>
  <summary>summary</summary>
  details
</details>

<input value="input">
```

Comment: Most modern websites always hide the outline, as they favor a better design over accessibility. I couldn't find a way to do it in pure CSS but [this article](https://medium.com/hackernoon/removing-that-ugly-focus-ring-and-keeping-it-too-6c8727fefcd2) could be useful if you are ok with using JS.

Comment: @HackerMan Thanks. This is exactly what I searched for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work without any issues
https://codepen.io/arun369/pen/qBRpmqj

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
        summary {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

/* The sledgehammer. It removes focus for both
 * select-with-Tab-key and expand events
 **/


/* summary:focus { outline: none; } */


/* An attempt of more intelligent approach. However,
 * it doesn't really work.
 **/

details[open] summary,
summary:active {
  outline: none;
}

summary:focus{}
summary._clicked:focus{outline:none}

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <button>button</button>

<details>
  <summary id="summary">summary</summary>
  details
</details>

<input value="input">


<script type="text/javascript">
var my_summary = document.getElementById('summary');

//add a class if mouse click is done, use it to stylize
my_summary.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    summary.className = '_clicked';
});

//remove class if tab is used
my_summary.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 9) {
        summary.className = '';
    }
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**What I did-**

1. Add event listener for clicking, so once you click it adds a class
2. Use that class to know how they are going through page, with tab or with mouse
3. If tab key is detected, remove the class and use the css accordingly to stylize.

Also, when you go back from clicking to tabbing, this works pretty well.

**Note**
If the summary element is expanded it will not show outline by default.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `border: none;` That should solve your issue

Comment: Hmm. This answer is voted 3 times, but it doesn't work for me. Here is a test: https://jsfiddle.net/wtbgz1k6/

Comment: that's odd because this website shows no outline for me